# How can I push all elements from the top when I use slidetoggle on the footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a footer, and when this one is clicked I want it to slide toggle up and push all the elements from the top without overlapping them.

This is the first view
[image]

And this is the view after clicking the yellow element

[image]

I was not able to reproduce this on jsfiddle. Here is my css, my js and my bottom html

```
$("li#dropdown").on('click', function(e) {
    $('#toggleList').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is my bottom CSS, using LESS

```
footer {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:36px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    nav {
        //margin-top:36px;
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            text-align: center;
            li {
                display:inline-block;
                a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font: normal 16px "proxima_novasemibold", helvetica;
                    color: #828282;
                    padding:0 8px;
                    margin-left: 5px;
                    &:hover {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: @pale-green;
                    }
                }
                &#dropdown {
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }
            li:last-child a span {
                background:url(../img/arrow.jpg) no-repeat;    
                width:16px;
                height:12px;
                display:inline-block;
                margin-left: 5px;
            }
        }
        .franchise-list {
            text-align: justify;
            display: inline-block;
            margin:23px 0;
            h4 {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                margin:5px 0;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #666;                    
            }
            span {

            }
            .franchise-col {
                float:left;
                font-size: 11px;
                margin-left:20px;
            }
        }
    }
    .bottom-info {
        font: normal 12px "proxima_novasemibold", helvetica;
        padding-top: 26px;
        padding-bottom: 18px;
        background-color: #F8F8F8;
        text-align: center;
        span {
            color:#696969;
        }
        div {
            display:inline;
            color: #199151;
            a {
                color:#199151;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

And Here is my bottom HTML

```
<footer>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT APPLE AUTO GLASS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SIX POINT CARE PROCESS&#8482;</a></li>
        <li><a href="">HASSLE FREE INSURANCE CLAIMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
        <li id="dropdown"><a>APPLE AUTO GLASS STORES<span class="dropdown-stores"></span></a></li>
    </ul>  
    <div class="franchise-list" id="toggleList" style="display:none;">   
    <?php 
        $regions = [];
        $listFranchises = [];
    ?>
@foreach($franchises as $key => $value)            
        <?php 
            $listFranchises[$key] = [$value->region, $value->town, $value->address];
            if (!(in_array($value->region, $regions))) {
                array_push($regions, $value->region);
            }                                     
        ?>
@endforeach
    <?php
        $counter = 0;
        $franchiseList = count($listFranchises) + count($regions);
        $marker = true;
        foreach($regions as $region) {           
            if ($counter%14 === 0 && $marker) {
                echo ('<div class="franchise-col">');             
            }
            else {
                $marker = true;
            }
            $counter += 1;
            echo ('<h4 counter="'.$counter.'/'.$franchiseList.'">'.$region.'</h4>');               
            foreach($listFranchises as $key => $value) {                  
                if($region === $value[0]) {
                    $counter += 1;
                    echo ('<span counter="'.$counter.'/'.$franchiseList.'"><a href="#">'.$value[1].'</a> - '.$value[2].'</span><br>');
                    if ($counter%14 === 0) {
                        echo ('</div>');
                    }
                    if ($counter%14 === 0 && ($franchiseList-$counter > 0)) {
                        echo ('<div class="franchise-col">'); 
                        $marker = false;
                    }
                    if (($franchiseList - $counter) == 0) {
                        echo ('</div>');
                    }
                } 
            }                 
        }
    ?>  

    </div>
</nav>
<div class="bottom-info">
    <span>Copyright &#169; <?php echo date('Y') ?> Apple Auto Glass &#174;. All Rights Reserved.</span>
    <div>
        <a href="">Terms of Use</a> |
        <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're already doing what is required to make it grow upward (absolutely positioned footer attached to bottom.) What is currently happening instead? is it just growing too tall?

Comment: If that's the case, what is dictating how much space comes between the footer and the content of the page?

Comment: yeah like you see in the picture, the footer overlaps the content when its toggled. And I just want to push everything on top

Comment: sort of like this but at the bottom http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/b6rkb/24/

Comment: or more precisely, this: http://jsfiddle.net/b6rkb/35/ you want it to start growing downward once it gets to the bottom of .page.

Comment: but still overlapping the content :(

Comment: Right, i didn't suggest it as a solution, i'm recreating your problem.

Comment: thank you! I am trying to find a quick solution :(

Comment: I don't really think there will be an elegant solution to this. you'll have to adjust the bottom position of the footer based on it's height and the bottom of the div it's trying to go up against above. no matter what you do there's going to be an ugly jumping effect while you alter the bottom position.

Comment: yeah looks horrible, but I hope my client can live with it

Comment: The first half of the animation is easy. http://jsfiddle.net/b6rkb/37/ getting the second half though is being a little difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, not optimized or cleaned up at all, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6rkb/40/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var panelHeight = $("#panel").show().height(),
        docHeight = $(document).height(),
        panelToggle = false,
        maxTopOffset = $(".page").offset().top + $(".page").outerHeight();
    $("#panel").css("height","0px");
    $("#flip").click(function () {
        var targetHeight;
        if (panelToggle) {
            targetHeight = 0;
        } else {
            targetHeight = panelHeight;   
        }
        panelToggle = !panelToggle;
        $("#panel").finish().animate({
            height: targetHeight   
        },{
            step: function(height) {
                if (panelToggle) {
                    var distance = maxTopOffset - $(".footer").offset().top;                
                    if (distance > -10) {
                        $(".footer").css("position","relative");
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(docHeight,$(document).height())
                    if ($(document).height() == docHeight) {
                        $(".footer").css("position","absolute");
                    }                    
                }

            },
            duration: 500
        });
    });
});
```

It uses two different techniques.

When opening the panel, i check the distance between the top of the panel and the bottom of the page. When it is 10px from the bottom or less, i change the position of the footer to block so that it won't overlap.

When closing the panel, I wait for the body height to go back to it's original height. When that happens, I change the position back to absolute. Obviously you will have to modify this to fit your page, but the concept should work.